# Is there a 3rd party X-mount lens (price & function) similar to Fujinon's portrait lens?

Tags: portrait, fujifilm, olympus, lens-recommendation

I'm interested in these two lenses for portraiture:

- X-mount Fujinon XF 56mm F1.2 R
- Micro Four Thirds' Olympus M. Zuiko Digital ED 45mm f1.8

The problem is I want a decent portrait lens, but the Fujinon runs USD $1000. I'd rather pay the price of the Olympus lens (USD $400).

So I'd really like to know if there is a comparable lens in X-mount, but priced like the Olympus, that I simply don't know about.

I'd also be interested in a decent (affordably-priced & technically feasible) adapter that will allow me to use the Olympus lens with the Fujifilm X-E2 without many drawbacks? (My highest priority being quick AF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. The 35/1.4 is probably the closest you can get in that price range. Zeiss Touits aren't exactly cheap, and the Samyang/Rokinon X lenses aren't exactly small and compact, as they're mostly dSLR lens designs with an X mount.  And the one that isn't is a fisheye.

Adapting mft to Fuji X is also probably not a good idea. The four-thirds format is smaller than APS-C (2x crop vs. 1.5x crop).  If you do find an adapter, chances are very very good that it will vignette (i.e., the image circle of the Olympus lens will not cover the image sensor of the Fuji).  In addition, the 45/1.8 has no aperture ring, and there will be no electronic communication from the camera to the lens, so there will be no way to control the aperture, and that means you have to shoot wide open all the time with it.

If you really don't mind the PITAness of a manual-everything lens (stop-down metering, holes in the EXIF lens information, manual focusing, manual aperture setting, etc. etc.) Your best bet might be to find a vintage 50/1.8 or something like the Cosina Voigtländer M-mount rangefinder lenses, like the [Nokton 40/1.4](http://voigtlaender.de/40-mm-f-1%2c4-nokton.html). About $450, compact almost-pancake build, built like a tank. But the m.Zuiko 45/1.8 costs less (I got one refurbished off the Olympus website for roughly US$350) and autofocuses.

I hate to say it, but if lower-cost autofocusing lenses are a must for you, then give up the X-Trans colors, and swap out to an MFT body.  Just my personal opinion, but you go to MFT for the lens selection, to Fuji for the haptics and colors, and NEX for the sensors. Fuji very much looks like their aesthetic and design for the X mount is going to be high quality fast lenses, which means expensive glass.  Note how they come out with a lot of f/1.4 primes, and no f/1.8 ones, and their first portrait prime is an f/1.2.  Faster means more expensive.

Comment: I thought some adapters allow some electronic communication through. Is this true? If it is, how can you tell if an adaptor will allow some communication, or none at all?

Comment: FYI my background is: this will be my first camera above a PowerShot (haven't bought it yet, leaning toward Oly OMD-EM5 or Fuji X-E2). I'm asking questions about lenses so I can decide between the 2, and it seems I'm now leaning towards MFT.

Comment: If you see contacts for the camera, then it will do some electronic communication; and typically the specs on an adapter will mention if you get aperture control/AF/EXIF, but AFAIK, not even Novoflex is making AF adapters for Fuji X.

Bear in mind that Fuji X is four years younger (2012) than MFT (2008), and that MFT is being produced by two separate companies. In another four years, the landscape may look a little different. But [Fuji's lens roadmap](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/xf_lens/roadmap/) is worth studying against the mft lineup.

Answer (score 0):

A cheap solution is to use a legacy wide aperture lens with its X-mount adapter.

You loose Autofocus but you keep manual focusing helpers : focus peaking etc.

See here for an example [Minolta Rokkor MD 50mm f/1.2 review](http://goo.gl/RD7cVA)

Comment: Given that the original poster's highest priority was "quick AF", I don't think an adapted lens really fits the bill here.

Comment: Sure, this can be a big trade off for some.